# cache data feed for webpage

Tags: php, mysql, html, datafeed

I'm still a novice website builder, so please go easy on me ...

I am displaying a webpage onto a TV viewable to the public.  There is a networked media player behind the TV which plays the webpage, it's not a PC.

The webpage displays regularly updated data which comes from a MySQL database, and I simply use a page refresh to update the webpage.  So everything works well, however ...  if there is a loss of internet connection, then of course an error appears on the TV when the page refreshes.

Is there a way to remove the page refresh, have a piece of code that will still retrieve the data in the background, and ideally cache that data so that even if there is a loss of internet the TV will still continue to display correctly (even if the data is slightly outdated) ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is the user-agent JavaScript capable?  Look into "service workers"....

Comment: If only PHP, do you have a writable filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for AJAX. You could also look into service workers.

Comment: I don't know anything about service workers, but yes it does seem that perhaps AJAX could provide the solution.  Thanks.